# need to build a neural network in rstudio for an exchange rate

Tags: r, neural-network

i have a set of data with these columns YY/MM//DD, Day , USD/EUR. in the specification is mentioned to only use the third column USD/EUR, but i dont know how to build a neural network with just that column.

Here is what i got

```
str(exchange)
summary(exchange)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)

melted_exchange = melt(exchange)
tail(melted_exchange)
qplot(x=value, data=melted_exchange) + facet_wrap(~variable, scales='free')
normalize <- function(x) {
  return((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

exchange_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(exchange, normalize))

summary(exchange_norm)   

exchange_train <- exchange_norm[1:375,]
exchange_test <- exchange_norm[376:500,]


library(neuralnet)
library(grid)
library(MASS)

set.seed(12345)
exchange_model <- neuralnet( ,data = exchange_train)
plot(exchange_model)
```

Comment: You can select the 3rd column when you split the normalized data into test / train sets like so: `exchange_norm[1:375,][3]` and `exchange_norm[376:500,][3]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forecast` package for fitting neural network on time Series data like

```
library(forecast)

normalize <- function(x) {
  return((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

data(lynx)

exchange_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(lynx, normalize))
colnames(exchange_norm) <- "exchange"
summary(exchange_norm)   

#Convert again to time series data
exchange_norm <- ts(exchange_norm,frequency=1,start=c(1821, 1), end=c(1934, 1))

# subset the time series
exchange_train <- window(exchange_norm, start=c(1821, 1), end=c(1900, 1))
exchange_test <- window(exchange_norm, start=c(1901, 1), end=c(1934, 1))

## Fit model to the exchange_train data
fit <- nnetar(exchange_train, decay=0.5, maxit=150)
#Predict on exchange_test data
plot(forecast(fit,h=34))
lines(exchange_test)
```